# How to debug in TYPO3 if <f:debug> returns strings instead of object?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-8.7.x

In a custom TYPO3 8.7.12 extbase extension I am unable to `f:debug` items in templates.

We are in the listAction controller and simply do:

```
    $institutions = $this->institutionRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assignMultiple([
        'institutions' => $institutions,
        // ... pagination limit ...
        ]
    );
```

And in the template:

```
 <f:debug>
    {institutions}                            
 </f:debug>
```

This returns

- sometimes the string 'Array' in the fluid debugger (can't reproduce now)
- When the code is on 3 lines: `#1273753083: Cannot cast object of type "TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResult" to string.`
- Or also `#1273753083: Cannot cast object of type "TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\LazyObjectStorage" to string.`
- When the code is on 1 line: `#1234386924: Cannot create empty instance of the class "TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage" because it does not implement the TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\DomainObjectInterface.`

If I loop through {institutions} with `f:for` and then `f:debug`:

```
<f:for each="{institutions}" as="institution" iteration="i">
    <f:debug>
      {institution}
    </f:debug>
</f:for>
```

I get the first property of the object, e.g. the name.

**EDIT:** this is due to a `__toString()` magic method in the model. If I remove it, instead I get the namespace and uid `STUBR\Extension\Domain\Model\Institution:55` – this looks again as if the object isn't rendered.

**Wait...** php.net says `The __toString() method allows a class to decide how it will react when it is treated like a string`. So could something be treating (typecasting?) the object as a string?

Working with the properties is normal, the issue just occurs when trying to print the whole object.

Where should I look? Lazy loading? There are some lazy loading properties, but not that many. Or maybe something is missing from the class? Or is there a workaround.

PS:

- Unable to print_r or var_dump the query result, I get a memory limit error.
- I saw https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1234386924 but  `initStorageObjects()` is already called in the constructor

Comment: Hmmm... I had similar "surprises"... 
- Did you try debug() in your controller? (so not in Fluid...) 
- Did you try a simple $this->view->assign('institutions', $institutions) and debug $institutions?
- Did you try to remove @lazy for the moment?
Could you also post the Fluid code, please?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. `simple $this->view->assign('institutions', $institutions)` and `remove @lazy`: I did, no difference. `Did you try debug() in your controller?` There's no such php command, what do you mean? print_r uses too much memory

Comment: Debug() is the TYPo3 standard debugging method:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Examples/Debugging/Index.html
https://somethingphp.com/debugging-typo3/

Comment: Thanks Robert! `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\DebugUtility::debug` works perfectly and produces the same output as expected from f:debug

Comment: If you post that as answer I can accept it

Comment: Well, I guess my comment does not answer you question... :-) But if you have an answer in the meantime, post it and I can vote on it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the question;

```
<f:debug>{institutions}</f:debug>
```

will be parsed as an object, but *any* whitespace inside will make it parse as a string so.

Answer (score 1):

The following methods do the same job as `<f:debug>` and work similarly in my case:

```
     \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\DebugUtility::debug(
        $var = $variable,
        $header = 'Institutions',
        $group = ''
     );

     \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump(
        $variable,
        $title = 'Institutions', 
        $maxDepth = 8,
        $plainText = FALSE,
        $ansiColors = TRUE,
        $return = FALSE,
        $blacklistedClassNames = NULL,
        $blacklistedPropertyNames = NULL
     );
```

execute in list or show action in controller.

It's less convenient than with f:debug (because you have to do the work in two different places, e.g. when you're in a loop in the template, you have to go to the controller and build that loop again), but it's a helpful workaround.

**EDIT:** I found it's sufficient to do

`<f:debug>{var}</f:debug>`

on one line

Comment: it's useful to use as title in `DebuggerUtility::var_dump` or as header in `DebugUtility::debug` this: `__CLASS__ . ':' . __LINE__` like that you find always directly in which file the debug is used and you've never to search. Also you've never to adjust that if you copy debug-commands, as it's self-adjusting.